# Using join in update command in trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

I have 3 tables

'stockMedicina' (farmaciaID,seriemedicina,stock)

'Factura' (farmaciaid,facturaid)

'DetalleFactura' (facturaid,seriemedicina,cantidad)

and i want to update the inventory of stockMedicina which is an int named stock when i insert a new value to detalleFactura. So when i insert a new value in detalleFactura i want to update the inventory of the farmaciaid which is on the factura table to decrease the amount of stock. I have this code but it doesn't work, and i don't know what to do now. :(

```
DELIMITER $$;
CREATE TRIGGER diminuirStock
AFTER INSERT ON detalleFactura 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE stockmedicina sm
    INNER JOIN factura fa ON sm.farmaciaid = fa.farmacia
    INNER JOIN detalleFactura df ON sm.seriemedicina = df.seriemedicina AND fa.facturaID=df.facturaID
    SET sm.stock = sm.stock - NEW.cantidad
    WHERE sm.FarmaciaID = fa.Farmacia and sm.seriemedicina=NEW.facturaID
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Any thought or help about it would be really helpful :c

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text. Also, what do you mean by *does not work*? Are you getting an error (which one?), wrong results, else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your columns have the false column name

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE stockMedicina (farmaciaID INT,seriemedicina INT ,stock INT);
INSERT INTO stockMedicina VALUES (1,1,10);

CREATE TABLE Factura (farmaciaid INT, faturaid INT);
INSERT INTO Factura VALUES (1,1);

CREATE TABLE DetalleFactura (facturaid INT ,seriemedicina INT ,cantidad INT);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER diminuirStock
AFTER INSERT ON DetalleFactura 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE stockMedicina sm
    INNER JOIN Factura fa ON sm.farmaciaID = fa.farmaciaid
    INNER JOIN DetalleFactura df ON sm.seriemedicina = df.seriemedicina AND fa.faturaid=df.facturaID
    SET sm.stock = sm.stock - NEW.cantidad
    WHERE sm.FarmaciaID = fa.farmaciaid and sm.seriemedicina=NEW.facturaid;
END$$
DELIMITER ; 
INSERT INTO DetalleFactura VALUES (1,1,2)
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM stockMedicina;

| farmaciaID | seriemedicina | stock |
| ---------- | ------------- | ----- |
| 1          | 1             | 8     |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/27Rv4Jz8CEm7r8TxYLVfC6/9)